# NSQueue - несколько потоков

Tags: xcode, потоки-данных, iphone, objective-c

Здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки, я тут недавно задавал вопрос о выполнении NSTimer в цикле, мне все в один голос советовали использовать NSQueue. Ок, прислушался, но проблема не решается и с использованием и этого метода. Сможете помочь?
Нижеуказанный код исполняется в DidLoad.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
..........
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

NSOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
 initWithTarget:self
 selector:@selector(myMethod)
 object:nil];

[queue addOperation:operation];
}
 .................
```

Вот у меня, по идее, должно было открыться два потока, в каждом из которых должен выполниться myMethod, но в первом выполниться действия для элементов где i=0, ну и соответственно во втором для элементов где i=1.
Но у меня почему то выполняются действия только для i=1, как будто для i=0 он "пролетает" и не делает.
Если же цикл изменить на i < 1 , т.е. для одного элемента сделать - все делает правильно.

Comment: то есть пролетает? myMethod вызывается один раз вместо двух?

Comment: Да. Метод вызывается один раз. Максим, пресловутая картинка "моргает" только последняя. :))
Вместо двойки (i) может быть 3 и 4 и 5, в оригинале там стоит переменная.
А "моргает", т.е. выполняется myMethod только для последней итерации (моргает последняя картинка)
Т.о.  как вы правильно заметили, не зависимо от значения i , myMethod выполняется только один раз - для последнего элемента в итерации.

Comment: блин тут может быть куча причин, пошарьте проект чтоли. Так будет легче разобраться. А пока интересна имплементация метода myMethod. Где-то, косяк. Либо в потоках либо в коде. То что вы опубликовали, должно работать.

Comment: Все, задача решена передачей дополнительного параметра через object.